# FreeRadius / Daloradius: Database connection error & extension not found

Tags: mysql, freeradius

I installed FreeRadius and the Webinterface Daloradius.
Unfortunately I'm not able to log in to http://radiusip/daloradius.

I always receive the error message:

Database connection error
Error Message: DB Error: extension not found

The Log always writes this, when I quit the Debugging (FreeRadius -X):

```
tail -f /var/log/mysql/error.log:

2016-08-26T10:33:54.070388Z 444 [Note] Aborted connection 444 to db: 'radius' user: 'freeradius' host: 'localhost' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2016-08-26T10:33:54.070498Z 443 [Note] Aborted connection 443 to db: 'radius' user: 'freeradius' host: 'localhost' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2016-08-26T10:33:54.070613Z 442 [Note] Aborted connection 442 to db: 'radius' user: 'freeradius' host: 'localhost' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2016-08-26T10:33:54.070677Z 441 [Note] Aborted connection 441 to db: 'radius' user: 'freeradius' host: 'localhost' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2016-08-26T10:33:54.070788Z 440 [Note] Aborted connection 440 to db: 'radius' user: 'freeradius' host: 'localhost' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2016-08-26T10:33:54.070979Z 439 [Note] Aborted connection 439 to db: 'radius' user: 'freeradius' host: 'localhost' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2016-08-26T10:33:54.071049Z 438 [Note] Aborted connection 438 to db: 'radius' user: 'freeradius' host: 'localhost' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2016-08-26T10:33:54.071159Z 437 [Note] Aborted connection 437 to db: 'radius' user: 'freeradius' host: 'localhost' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2016-08-26T10:33:54.071274Z 436 [Note] Aborted connection 436 to db: 'radius' user: 'freeradius' host: 'localhost' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2016-08-26T10:33:54.071306Z 455 [Note] Aborted connection 455 to db: 'radius' user: 'freeradius' host: 'localhost' (Got an error reading communication packets)
```

The Password is 100 % Correct in all necessary Config-Files, I deactived the Firewall. I think it has to do with not properly closing connections and/or wrong permissions.

The Permissions from The MySql-User are:

```
mysql> show grants;
+----------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for freeradius@localhost                                |
+----------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'freeradius'@'localhost'                 |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `radius`.* TO 'freeradius'@'localhost' |
+----------------------------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Any Ideas?

It is Ubuntu 16.04, Daloradius 0909 and FreeRadius V3

Answer (score 2):

I managed to got this working.
In case you struggling with the same problems, this helped me out:

The Problem is, i had PHP7.0 installed, but daloradius is only supportet until 5.0
So we have to change the rules for syntax reading. with the following commands:

1. Make Sure you got all neccessary packages

   `sudo apt-get install php-common php-gd php-curl php-mail php-mail-mime php-pear php-dbnter code here
   sudo apt-get install php-common php-gd php-curl php-mail php-mail-mime php-pear php-db
   pear install DB
   cd /var/www/html/daloradius/library/
   vim daloradius.conf.php -> CONFIG_DB_ENGINE auf "mysqli" # from mysql to mysqli
   vim opendb.php -> $dbSocket->query("SET GLOBAL sql_mode = '';"); #append this line at the end of the file`
2. Now we have to give the db-user freeradius super rights with:

`mysql -u root -p 
mysql> GRANT SUPER ON *.* TO 'freeradius'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
mysql> flush privileges;`

3. I had to import a mysql schema with:

`cd /var/www/html/daloradius/contrib/db/
mysql -u root -p radius <mysql-daloradius.sql`

Comment: THANK YOU! Caps on purpose! P.S. For me it worked without $dbSocket->query("SET GLOBAL sql_mode = '';"); line. With it I got another error.

Answer (score 1):

I got here because I got the same error message after trying to login. But had no errors logged in MySQL and FreeRadius. So I restarted my Ubuntu Server and the error message disappeared.

Comment: Crazy, but it works -- i had the same problem on debian 11. Reboot helped. Mariadb was working, freeradius refused to start until I rebooted debian.